# Python list of versions without distutils.version

Tags: python, python-3.x, versioning, distutils

How can I sort a list of versions without using distutils?

`distutils.version` has a limit to how long a version number can be and so I get

## StrictVersion

```
msg": "invalid version number '11.2.0.4.v4'"
```

## LooseVersion

```
"results": null
```

## Results without sorting

```
["11.2.0.4.v4", "11.2.0.4.v5", "11.2.0.4.v6", "11.2.0.4.v7", "11.2.0.4.v8", 
 "11.2.0.4.v9", "11.2.0.4.v10", "11.2.0.4.v11", "11.2.0.4.v12", 
 "11.2.0.4.v13", "11.2.0.4.v14", "11.2.0.4.v15", "11.2.0.4.v16", 
 "11.2.0.4.v17", "12.1.0.2.v1", "12.1.0.2.v2", "12.1.0.2.v3", "12.1.0.2.v4", 
 "12.1.0.2.v5", "12.1.0.2.v6", "12.1.0.2.v7", "12.1.0.2.v8", "12.1.0.2.v9", 
 "12.1.0.2.v10", "12.1.0.2.v11", "12.1.0.2.v12", "12.1.0.2.v13"]
```

## Pertinent code

```
try:
    params = dict()
    params['Engine'] = module.params.get('engine_name')
    results = client.describe_db_engine_versions(**params)
    versions = [z['EngineVersion'] for z in results['DBEngineVersions']]
    return versions.sort(key=StrictVersion)        
except Exception as e:
    module.fail_json(msg=str(e))
```

Comment: Added question, fixed typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally this would be done using [`packaging.version.Version`](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/version.html), but it won't work in this case since the strings are not valid version numbers according to [the specification](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/).

```
>>> from packaging.version import parse
>>> parse("11.2.0.4.v4")
InvalidVersion: Invalid version: '11.2.0.4.v4'
```

You may use [looseversion](https://github.com/effigies/looseversion) for ordering these strings. It is a backwards/forwards-compatible fork of the deprecated `distutils.version.LooseVersion` type, for occasions when strict PEP 440 constraints on the data are undesirable.

```
>>> from looseversion import LooseVersion
>>> sorted(vs, key=LooseVersion)
['11.2.0.4.v4',
 '11.2.0.4.v5',
 '11.2.0.4.v6',
 '11.2.0.4.v7',
 '11.2.0.4.v8',
 '11.2.0.4.v9',
 '11.2.0.4.v10',
 '11.2.0.4.v11',
 '11.2.0.4.v12',
 '11.2.0.4.v13',
 '11.2.0.4.v14',
 '11.2.0.4.v15',
 '11.2.0.4.v16',
 '11.2.0.4.v17',
 '12.1.0.2.v1',
 '12.1.0.2.v2',
 '12.1.0.2.v3',
 '12.1.0.2.v4',
 '12.1.0.2.v5',
 '12.1.0.2.v6',
 '12.1.0.2.v7',
 '12.1.0.2.v8',
 '12.1.0.2.v9',
 '12.1.0.2.v10',
 '12.1.0.2.v11',
 '12.1.0.2.v12',
 '12.1.0.2.v13']
```

Comment: Works famously. Appreciate the help.